# Multiple string inputs in Python

Tags: python, split, user-input

I have the following minimal code where I want to make a plot by reading a data file specified by the user. In the plot, I want the *x* and *y* labels also to be specified by the user.

```
# ReadFileAndPlot.py
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
# Use numpy to load the data contained in the file
datafile=raw_input('Enter data filename\n')
print 'Data filename :',datafile

x,y=map(string,raw_input('Enter x and y axis labels\n').split())
#x='Current'; y='Voltage'

data = np.loadtxt(datafile)

# plot the first column as x, and second column as y
pl.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], 'ro')
pl.xlabel(x)
pl.ylabel(y)
pl.xlim(0.0, 10.)
pl.show()
```

However, *strings* are not recognized while feeding them as multiple inputs using `split`. So I get the message : `NameError: name 'string' is not defined` [works with `int` variables though].

Any way to correct this using `split` or something similar?

Comment: Use `str` instead of `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use map. Simply split and assign tuple to x and y. But it will not ensure that user has given valid input (mean two words). If there will be more than two words it will break.

```
while True:
    try:
        x, y = raw_input('Enter x and y axis labels\n').split()
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input.')
```

Comment: You don't need the `valid` stuff here... Use a `while True:` and `break` when you've got valid input...

Comment: @JonClements Then it will require us to define x and y outside loop otherwise it will give us refrence error. `while not(x and y):`

Comment: That's not the case. The loop won't exit until there's valid input and at that point x and y will be bound - see https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e777cfef18aa6f83e9a64f0ff81f625b

Answer (score 0):

Use str instead of string:

```
x,y=map(str, raw_input('Enter x and y axis labels\n').split())
```